# Deployment error_connection_refused

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I have a nodejs app with angular for front end, I deployed the app on GCP App engine and it gives me this error when pressing the login button:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

If I start the server.js on my local host it works just fine on the deployed site.

This is the app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs18
env: standard
instance_class: F1
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
 }
}
```

I think I have done something wrong somewhere in my configuration.

Comment: Did you have check the logs in Cloud Logging?